# Strange behavior of enumitem

Tags: enumitem

I want to align an enumeration on the left margin, So I use enumitem and `leftmargin=*`. If there are more than 9 items 1 of the 10 is in the margin

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Is it normal? how I can fixed it ? (I don't want 1 in margin)

I don't find any answered or my english is too bad.

Answer (score 4):

By default the numbers are right aligned. You can left align them if you prefer this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep,align=left]
\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can make the labelwidth larger:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[labelwidth=1.5em,leftmargin=!,noitemsep]
\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item\item blbl\\blbl
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]` option also does the job.

Comment: now item are not aligned. no way to have both?

Comment: In my second example the items are aligned, see the blbl beside the 12.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 ... are not align on margin. I've already find a solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep,labelsep=! ,align=parleft]
\item a 
\item b 
\item c
\item d
\item e 
\item f
\item g
\item h 
\item i
\item j
\item k
\item l
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```